# Webserver VPN tunnel

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding, webserver

I run a small server in my dorm, I need to be able to access it from the internet but I can't port forward on my schools local network. I have a PC at home that is ssh capable. I can port forward on my home network so I want to use that PC at home to access my server from the internet.

For clarification:

USER --> INTERNET --> HOME-PC --> DORM-SERVER

What do I need to do this?

EDIT:

More like this: 
USER --> INTERNET --> HOME-PC <--VPN--> DORM-SERVER

Comment: is your home (and the home network) at the dorm or somewhere else ? If somewhere else then it's more like: *USER --> INTERNET --> HOME-PC --> INTERNET --> DORM SERVER*. Can you tunnel from your PC to the Dorm-Server?

Comment: Your school probably has a firewall to keep out *inbound* connections.

Comment: @Smock you're right, the home pc is on a different local network. I think I may have phrased my question wrong, I need to tunnel from DORM-SERVER to HOME-PC so when I go to the IP of HOME-PC I get the webpage of DORM-SERVER. Mike Robinson you are also correct I cant get inbound connections. 

I guess what I really need is:

USER --> INTERNET --> HOME-PC <--VPN--> DORM-SERVER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do **reverse SSH**, for example using [autossh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh). In this setup, the server will connect (and reconnect as needed) to your home computer. You need to have SSH running on your home PC and set up port forwarding on your home router so that incoming requests reach your home PC.

Comment: Will this work for services other than ssh?

Comment: Yes, you can do port forwarding or proxying on an SSH tunnel, see for example https://www.howtogeek.com/168145/how-to-use-ssh-tunneling/